# How to get cropped image from cropper js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, cropperjs

I am trying to get cropped image result from cropperjs but I dont know how to get it. I tried to search online but couldn't find a solution.

My code is as given below.

```
$(function () 
  {


  $image=null;

  var img = document.createElement("IMG");
  img.src = "";
  img.setAttribute('id', "showImage");
  document.getElementById("img-container").appendChild(img);

  var url = canvas.toDataURL();
  canvasImage.src = url;
  console.log(canvasImage);

  document.getElementById("showImage").src=canvasImage.src;
  $image = $('#showImage');
  $image.cropper({
    movable: true,
    zoomable: false,
    rotatable: false,
    scalable: false
  });

  $('#replace').on('click', function () {   
    var croppedimage = new Image();
    var cropBoxData = $image.cropper('getCropBoxData');
    croppedimage=$image.data('cropper');
    // croppedimage= this.cropper.
    console.log($image);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML and describe what doesn't work with your code

Comment: you have to send it to the server to actually crop it for you.

Comment: Actually I am Making an Application

First I rendered pdf on canvas,
then I converted it into Image,
applied cropper on it.

I actually want to crop certain area of pdf file and send that image to OCR library.

Comment: $('#replace').on('click', function () {   
    var croppedimage = new Image();
    var cropBoxData = $image.cropper('getCropBoxData');
    croppedimage=$image.data('cropper');
    // croppedimage= this.cropper.
    console.log($image);
  });


At This part I want that cropper to crop the image for me.

Comment: @JosanIracheta How could I do that Please tell me I will be so thankful to you.

Comment: did you copy this code from somewhere?

Comment: Not 100% but yeah I was taking help online. Please guide me on the #replace click event. I want that if user clicks crop, I get another image in JS which the result of cropping.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#replace').on('click', function () {   
    var croppedimage = $image.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL("image/png");
    console.log(croppedimage);
});
```

you can get base64

Comment: I had to do this: `$image.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL("image/png");`. It worked great!

Comment: @Jarad thanks for the comment, it worked for me i guess the older version (i'm using 2017) works witht this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React, you should wait for the Cropper to be `ready` and then get the cropper instance (with imageData) from the `ready` event.

You can get the event like this:

```
const handleReady = useCallback((readyEvent: Cropper.ReadyEvent<HTMLImageElement>) => {
    const cropperInstance = readyEvent.currentTarget?.cropper;
    const imageData = readyEvent.currentTarget?.cropper.getImageData();
  }, []);


return (
  <Cropper
    ...
    ready={handleReady}
  />
);
```